# python coding and creating and SQlite

Tags: python, sqlite

Have a file that has  the months`( Jan, Feb, March,.... as variable and 5 levels(d0 to d4)` for each month
I want to create a new column called impacted if I have any d2 levels in 2 consecutive months in a row or any d3 or d4 levels for any months during the year.
I would like to do the same with SQLite

for example

```
jan...feb, mars April....nov  dec     impacted
0      d2  d2    0       0     0       yes
0      0    0    d3      0     0       yes
0      0    0     0      0     0       no
d4     0    0     0      0     0       yes
0      d2   0     0      0     0       no
d1     d0   d1    d0     d0    d1      no
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you want SQL code for SQLite then use a `CTE` and the operator `LIKE`:

```
with cte as (
  select *,
    ',' || jan ||',' || feb ||',' || mar ||',' || apr ||',' || may ||',' || jun ||
    ',' || jul ||',' || aug ||',' || sep ||',' || oct ||',' || nov ||',' || dec ||',' months
  from tablename
)
select jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec,
  case when (months like '%,d2,d2,%') or (months like '%,d3,%') or (months like '%,d4,%') then 'yes' else 'no' end impacted
from cte
```

This code will work if (like your sample data) there are not any `NULL`s in the table. If there are then you must use `coalesce()`.

Comment: why there are months there if it is not part of my variables and with python how would it be written